DART SIP_UA "call.hold()" only trigger callStateChanged on local side but not call callStateChanged on remote side
When I make call between 2 extension. If I call a function hold(), func callStateChanged() local side will be triggered but remote side not getting triggered. What the problem is when local user put call on hold, remote user won't know that.
What is solution?
